# I want to export all the entries to an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
#bll
import pickle
import pandas as pd
class Customer:
    cuslist=[]
    def __repr__(self):
        return(str(self))
    def __init__(self):
        self.id=0
        self.age=0
        self.name=0
        self.dateofBirth = 0
        self.address = 0
        self.phoneNumber = 0
        self.amount = 0
        self.zipCode = 0
        self.experience = 0
        self.form = 0

    def addcustomer(self):
        Customer.cuslist.append(self)
    def searchcustomer(self):
        for e in Customer.cuslist:
            if(e.id==self.id):
                self.age=e.age
                self.name=e.name
                self.dateofBirth = e.dateofBirth
                self.address = e.address
                self.phoneNumber = e.phoneNumber
                self.amount = e.amount
                self.zipCode = e.zipCode
                self.experience = e.experience
                self.form = e.form
                break
    def deletecustomer(self):
        for e in Customer.cuslist:
            if (e.id == self.id):
                Customer.cuslist.remove(e)
                break
    def updatecustomer(self):
        for e in Customer.cuslist:
            if(e.id==self.id):
                e.age=self.age
                e.name=self.name
                e.dateofBirth = self.dateofBirth
                e.address = self.address
                e.phoneNumber = self.phoneNumber
                e.amount = self.amount
                e.zipCode = self.zipCode
                e.experience = self.experience
                e.form = self.form
                break
    @staticmethod
    # def convertoExcel(self):
    #        df = pd.DataFrame(Customer.cuslist.self)
    #        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    #        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    #        writer.save()
    @staticmethod
    def savetoPickle():
        f=open("D://cetpa//mypickle.txt","wb")
        pickle.dump(Customer.cuslist,f)
        f.close()
    @staticmethod
    def loadfromPickle():
        f = open("D://cetpa//mypickle.txt", "rb")
        Customer.cuslist=pickle.load(f)
        f.close()

#pl
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    while(1):
        print("Enter 1 to Add Customer")
        print("Enter 2 to Search Customer")
        print("Enter 3 to Delete Customer")
        print("Enter 4 to Modify Customer")
        print("Enter 5 to Display All Customer")
        print("Enter 6 to Exit")
        ch = input("Enter A Number: ")
        if(ch=='1'):
            cus=Customer()
            cus.id=input("enter id: ")
            cus.age = input("enter age: ")
            cus.name = input("enter name: ")
            cus.dateofBirth = input("enter date of birth: ")
            cus.addcustomer()
            print("Added Successfully!!")
        elif(ch=="2"):
            cus=Customer()
            cus.id=input("Enter Customer ID: ")
            cus.searchcustomer()
            print("Customer ID: ",cus.id, "Customer Age: ", cus.age, "Customer Name: ",cus.name)
        elif(ch=="3"):
            cus=Customer()
            cus.id=input("Enter Customer ID: ")
            cus.deletecustomer()
            print("Entry Deleted!!")
        elif(ch=='4'):
            cus=Customer()
            cus.id=input("Enter Customer ID: ")
            cus.age=input("Enter Updated Customer Age: ")
            cus.name=input("Enter Updated Customer Name: ")
            cus.updatecustomer()
            print("Customer Updated Successfully!!")
        elif(ch=='5'):
            cus=Customer()
            for e in Customer.cuslist:
                print("Customer ID: ",e.id)
                print("Customer Age",e.age)
                print("Customer Name: ",e.name)
                print("Customer Date of Birth: ",e.dateofBirth)
        elif (ch == '6'):
            Customer.savetoPickle()
        elif (ch == '7'):
            Customer.loadfromPickle()
        elif (ch == '8'):
            print(Customer.cuslist)
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing Or i should ask what you have tried till now? My simple suggestion will be to search for python library which can help you exporting data in excel and integrate it in your code

Answer (score 1):

Look into openpyxl.

It's a python module that lets you do stuff like this:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active

sheet['A1'] = "name"
sheet['A2'] = customer1.name
sheet['A3'] = customer2.name
sheet['B1'] = "age"
sheet['B2'] = customer1.age
sheet['B3'] = customer2.age

book.save("my_excel_file.xlsx")
```